# Strange behaviour of Cases and pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching, filtering

I have encountered a strange pattern matching behaviour which I cannot explain even after going through manual again.

Why does the second line in the code yield different result? Is it a feature of wolfram language compiler or do I miss something important?

```
Cases[2 a (b + c), Times[__, Plus[_, _]], {0}]
Cases[2 a (b + c), Times[__, Plus[__, __]], {0}]
Cases[2 a (b + c), Times[__, Plus[_, __]], {0}]
Cases[2 a (b + c), Times[__, Plus[__, _]], {0}]
Cases[2 a (b + c), Times[__, Plus[___, ___]], {0}]
```

```
{2 a (b + c)}
{}
{2 a (b + c)}
{2 a (b + c)}
{2 a (b + c)}
```

Comment: Evaluate `Times[__, Plus[__, __]]`  to see why `Cases` returns `{}`.  Try `Cases[2 a (b + c), HoldPattern[Times[__, Plus[__, __]]], {0}]` to prevent evaluation of the LHS of the rule before pattern matching gets to work.

Comment: Thank you, that helps. But what is the reason for such a behaviour?
I could not find any reference or explanation of this anywhere

Comment: I mean, I understand what is happening, but the logic of it eludes me.

Comment: [tutorial/EvaluationInPatternsRulesAndDefinitions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationInPatternsRulesAndDefinitions.html) may be useful.

Comment: What specifically is confusing for you? Is that that `__ + __` evaluates to `2 __` just the same as `x + x` evaluates to `2 x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that functions used in defining the pattern (i.e. Times and Plus) are evaluated first, using pattern symbols like _, __ or ___ as arguments.

First, note that the fact that the expression `2 a (b+c)` matches the pattern in some of the examples you have given is a coincidence (as explained below). If you use the expression `3 a (b+c)`, you get the following results:

```
Cases[3 a (b + c), Times[__, Plus[_, _]], {0}]     (* {} *)  
Cases[3 a (b + c), Times[__, Plus[__, __]], {0}]   (* {} *)
Cases[3 a (b + c), Times[__, Plus[_, __]], {0}]    (* 3 a (b+c) *)
Cases[3 a (b + c), Times[__, Plus[__, _]], {0}]    (* 3 a (b+c) *) 
Cases[3 a (b + c), Times[__, Plus[___, ___]], {0}]  (* {} *)
```

Back to your examples. This is how the pattern section is evaluated for the first three cases:

**Case 1:** `Times[__, Plus[_, _]]`

`Plus[_, _]` evaluates to `_+_` , and then to `2 _` (this is the coincidental 2)

`Times` is therefore evaluated as `__(2 _)` and then to `2 _ __`, which **matches the expression**.

**Case 2:** `Times[__, Plus[__, __]]`

`Plus[__, __]` evaluates to `__+__` , and then to `2 __`.

`Times` is therefore evaluated as `__(2 __)` and then to `2 __ __` , and then to   `2 __^2` which **does not match the expression**.

**Case 3:** `Times[__, Plus[_, __]]`

`Plus[_, __]` evaluates to `_+__`

`Times` is therefore evaluated as `__(_+__)`, which **matches the expression**.